# Internet of Things Platform Starter-error BXNUI0005E

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

Getting error BXNUI0005E while creating a new device at Internet of Things Platform Starter at IBM Bluemix. Please help. Also i am unable to find my previous made device. Help

Comment: That error is normally seen when creating an application whose name is not unique, not device add.  Can you clarify exactly what is failing, maybe include a screenshot or the code you are using to create the device?  Also check if anything in your logs.

Comment: Did you change the application name? Did that approach solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, Thanks Bill. Changing the name did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As amadain mentioned in the comments - That error is normally seen when creating an application whose name is not unique.  Changing the application name to something unique should resolve the issue.